# Remotely connecting to a single node Cassandra clustor (on an EC2 instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tcp, cassandra, ip

I'm running a single node Cassandra cluster on a medium Ubuntu EC2 instance. Before making any changes to cassandra.yaml, I can connect to cassandra using `cqlsh`,

and running `netstat -ltn` logs:

`Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38807         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35835         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9160          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN`

And checking Cassandra service status shows it's **active (running)**

Trying to connect to the instance remotely using `cqlsh <instance public IP>` times out and I'm assuming that's because it's not listening for clients at the instance public IP.

So far I have tired:

- Changing `listen_address` to my my private instance IP
- Setting `start_rpc:true`, `rpc_address` to my private IP and `broadcast_address` to my public IP
- Setting `rpc_address` to 0.0.0.0 and `broadcast_rpc_address` to my public IP

Note: I am keeping `seeds: "127.0.0.1"` as is, since I don't have other seeds or nodes.

Making any of the above changes, I am no longer able to access Cassandra using `cqlsh` or `cqlsh <public IP>` locally (and remotely still no connecting), even in the instance terminal itself and I would I get **connection refused**. Also, `netstat -ltn` now logs:

`Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38807         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`
`tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN`

And Cassandra service status shows it as **active (exited)**

I would like to be able to connect to the instance remotely, but in making any changes to cassandra.yaml, I am no longer able to connect to it, even locally.

Also, I have the **security groups** setup on the instance for ports 80, 22, 9042 and 7000.

Any ideas why this is happening or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nodes which have both private and public IP addresses, you just need to set:

```
listen_address: private_ip
rpc_address: public_ip
```

You only need to set the `broadcast_address` to the node's public IP if there are nodes in another region so nodes can talk to each other across the WAN on EC2. This means that you need to rollback all the other properties you configured.

The `listen_address` is used for internode communication (**gossip** on port `7000`) which is why it's set to the private IP.

Apps/clients (`cqlsh` is just another client) connects to the nodes on the `rpc_address` so it needs to be set to an IP that is publicly accessible.

I've answered a similar question recently in this post https://community.datastax.com/questions/8867/ if you're interested in a bit more detail. Cheers!